# Possible to open local IE from Citrix based on the html link in some way?

Tags: internet-explorer, citrix, xenapp

We're running a bunch of applications through our Citrix setup. But I have a case where a specific link on a html page should open the local IE instead of the IE in Citrix. Is this possible? If it is, can someone give me some input on how to do it?

Comment: Are you opening the link out of Citrix locally and not in Citrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Redirection which is a feature of Xenapp.  You will find that you can redirect content based on file extensions.  This can be found under Farm Properties in Citrix Access Management console.  Not exactly sure where this feature is in Delivery Center console.
Delivery center console is the new name for AMC in Version 6 of Xenapp and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this link?  http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/general/client-server-content-redirection-explained.html  This might be able to help with what you are looking for.